# How do I keep Promises.all from hanging my process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, async-await

When I `await Promises.all`, my unit-test process (npm with Mocha) never exits, but when I `await` individual promises, it does.

```
async function f(){...}

async function getVals1() {
    const vals = await Promise.all([f(), f()]);
    return vals;
}

async function getVals2() {
    const vals = []
    vals.push(await f());
    vals.push(await f());
    return vals;
}
```

Important points:

- The values are all sccessfully returned from `await Promises.all`. They  are the expected values (i.e., not themselves Promises), the same as with individual `await`s. Everything works fine, but the  `npm` does not exit.
- The problem does not always occur, but I don't know what, if anything,  conditions the problem.
- The application uses MongoDB and non-closure of MongoDB connections can cause applications to hang. But I did check that MongoDB connections are closed (at the end of the test run, long after this `await` call; and  in any case the difference between `await Promise.all` and individual `await` is hard to explain.

Comment: Note there's really no point in async/await in getVals1, you can use a vanilla function and `return Promise.all([...])`. In terms of the question could you give a [mcve] of how you're invoking these, and what f does (does it have any state that might impact parallel rather than series execution, for example)?

Comment: "does it have any state" -- see edit re MongoDB; "minimal reproducible example" -- that is the hard part. I did try to narrow it down but  am having a hard time finding the condition that would trigger this behavior.

Comment: If it behaves stably with two awaits (i.e. series execution) but is flaky with Promise.all (i.e. parallel execution) then I'd be looking for shared state and race conditions of some kind, but the question is answerable in more detail as it stands.

Comment: //The problem does not always occur - this means there is no problem in promise handling. It is something to do with your back end  which behaved differently in different occasions. This problem of your back end cannot be reproduced by the code you have provided.

Comment: @CharlieH (This is backend code.) When the problem occurs, then it occurs consistently with  Promise.all and consistently does not occur with separate awaits.  And yes, there is something else (in my code) conditioning this difference. I would like to find out what that is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe "shared state and race conditions" Quite right. I wonder what.  I would suspect MongoClient,  but that  is (meant to be) safe for this type of code.

Comment: The logic is that there is no technical flaw in Promise.All(). If 5 promises are resolved with individual calls, they are guaranteed to be working well with Promise.all(). So, the problem is with the code you haven't posted here. (backend)

Comment: Please show us the code of the `f()` function. Somehow they seem to only work properly when called sequentially.

Comment: @CharlieH Quite right.

Comment: @bergi The problem occcurs in several places where I do Promise.all. In the simpliest case, the code makes a MongoDB saveDocuments. In other cases, the code makes a MongoDB query or pipeline-query and then processes the results.

Comment: @JoshuaFox Are these somehow interdependent? Is the only object they share that mongodb connection? How does the processing look like, could it be affected from outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by multiple *opening* of MongoDB clients, so that afterwards, while some were closed, some were not. A lock was needed around `mongoDbClient = await MongoClient.connect(...)`.

Answer (score -1):

It seems the problem is that one or more of your functions is not asynchronous. But without code it hard to understand